# Creating a combination for trees [Python]

Tags: python, combinations

I wanted to create an analogy to deliver my question. Let’s say we have 20 pits to plant trees and we have 6 kind of trees to plant. I want to get all the possible combinations of planting this trees. I have given a combination example on the figure. Also the actual code I've tried is below but gives MemoryError. but I'm fine with just getting the first combination using it in a loop then move onto another one. I don't need to keep whole array in one 3d array

```
import itertools
l = [False,True]
a=list(itertools.product(l,repeat=6))
a=list(itertools.product(a,repeat=20))
```

•   Trees’ names : A,B,C,D,E,F.

•   G is for no plantation.

•   We have unlimited amount of every tree. So we can plant the same tree to every pit.

•   We can leave every hole unplanted.

Representation of the given example:

[[A],[G],[D],[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G]]

Whole combinations can be in a 3d numpy array or we can iterate over every combination via for loop.

Output example:

[[[A],[G],[D],[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G]],

[[A],[G],[D],[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[A] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G] ,[G]],

…

[[A],[A],[A], [A], [A], [A], [A], [A], [A], [A], [A], [A], [A], [A], [A], [A], [A], [A], [A], [A]]]

[image]

Comment: have a look at [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)

Comment: did tried,gives MemoryError.

Comment: Can you please add this to the question and show the error output

Comment: I added the code I've tried. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course you'll get a memory error! Did you try to calculate the sizes of the lists you're trying to create???

Comment: I did, that's why I'm asking whether there is a way around to get the possible combinations

Comment: Let me help you: the first creation of `a` is a list of size `2**6 = 64` which is still quite reasonable. BUT then you create the product of that list with `20` (!!!) repetitions. This gives a list of the astronomical size `64**20` which is equivalent to `2**120` which is equivalent to the amount of all the sand grains in the planet + all the days the earth has lived + 2

Comment: I haven't understood the modeling here: the way you are doing at the moment seems to suggest that a site can get multiple trees (if you get more than one True). Is that correct? Otherwise wny not just model using another letter for "no tree" and that's it. This would reduce the size of `a` from 64 to 7, and 7 ** 20 is *just* 79792266297612001.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach is to model your problem with a list of cases: `A` -> `G` and then use `itertools.product()`. It may be possible that `list(itertools.product())` still gives you a memory error. In that case, just use `next()` to pull only the subsequent combination:

```py
import itertools
import string

cases = list(string.ascii_uppercase[:7])
gen = itertools.product(cases, repeat=20)


for i in range(10): 
    print(next(gen))
# ('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A')
# ('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B')
# ('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C')
# ('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'D')
# ('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'E')
# ('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'F')
# ('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'G')
# ('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A')
# ('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B')
# ('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C')
```